# Using Proc Transpose Wide to Long in SAS

Tags: sas, transpose

I have data that looks like the table below and i would like to transpose it much like i would with a pivot table in excel, but instead in SAS.  I've tried proc transpose but get "ERROR: The ID value "'**'n" occurs twice in the same BY group."

Have (call this Long):

| Class | Year | Dev_Qtr | Paid_Loss | Inc_Loss |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Segment A | 2004 | 3 | 1000000 | 1500000 |
| Segment A | 2004 | 6 | 950547 | 1425820.5 |
| Segment A | 2004 | 9 | 971746 | 1457619 |
| Segment A | 2004 | 15 | 912356 | 1368534 |
| Segment A | 2004 | 18 | 26916 | 40374 |
| Segment A | 2004 | 21 | 235696 | 353544 |
| Segment A | 2004 | 27 | 641805 | 962707.5 |
| Segment A | 2004 | 30 | 653554 | 980331 |
| Segment B | 2004 | 3 | 1000000 | 1500000 |
| Segment B | 2004 | 6 | 634698 | 952047 |
| Segment B | 2004 | 9 | 956788 | 1435182 |
| Segment B | 2004 | 15 | 18532 | 27798 |
| Segment B | 2004 | 18 | 686824 | 1030236 |
| Segment B | 2004 | 21 | 289675 | 434512.5 |
| Segment B | 2004 | 27 | 462303 | 693454.5 |
| Segment B | 2004 | 30 | 591880 | 887820 |

Want (call this Wide):

| Class | Year | Amount | 3 | 6 | 9 | 12 | 15 | 18 | 21 | 24 | 27 | 30 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Segment A | 2004 | USD_Paid_Loss | 1000000 | 950547 | 971746 | 912356 | 26916 | 235696 | 641805 | 653554 |  |  |
| Segment A | 2004 | USD_Inc_Loss | 1500000 | 1425820.5 | 1457619 | 1368534 | 40374 | 353544 | 962707.5 | 980331 |  |  |
| Segment B | 2004 | USD_Paid_Loss | 1000000 | 634698 | 956788 | 18532 | 686824 | 289675 | 462303 | 591880 |  |  |
| Segment B | 2004 | USD_Inc_Loss | 1500000 | 952047 | 1435182 | 27798 | 1030236 | 434512.5 | 693454.5 | 887820 |  |  |

The code i tried running is

```
proc transpose data=Long out=Wide name=Amount;      
     id Dev_Qtr;        
     var Paid_Loss Inc_Loss;        
     by Class Year;     
run;
```

and the error is "ERROR: The ID value "'**'n" occurs twice in the same BY group."

Is it possible to create an output like i'm trying to achieve in SAS with proc transpose or is there some better way to do this?  The example of data i'm showing has 2 classes across the same year for various quarters but the real data will extend across 10 years of history in this manner.  Maybe this requires some looping?

Would appreciate any help!  I'm by no means a SAS expert and this clearly seems outside my usual wheelhouse!

Comment: Like the error indicates, there is a `Dev_Qtr` value that appears more than once within at least one `Class` and `Year`. Inspect your data more closely (the error should also show which variable values this occurs for).

Comment: @PBulls sorry i typed too soon.  I wasn't expecting there to be a repeat of `Dev_Qtr` for each `Class` and `Year` because i've summed up the `Paid_Loss` and `Inc_Loss` and grouped by `Class` and `Year` in a prior step.  With how you see the data laid out above with no duplicates of `Dev_Qtr` by `Class` and `Year` would you expect the proc transpose would work?

Comment: `Dev_Qtr` does appear across multiple instances of `Year` for example.  Maybe i need to loop through 1 year and class at a time?

Comment: The code you show works on your example dataset. Somewhere in there there has to be a single combination of `Class` and `Year` that has a duplicate for `Dev_Qtr`. Try counting the number of rows in each, for example: `proc sql;  select distinct class, year, dev_qtr, count(*) as n from long group by 1, 2, 3 order by n desc;  quit;` (anything with n>1 will cause your transpose to fail).

Comment: @PBulls thanks i will give that a try to see if i can identify where it's going awry!

Comment: @PBulls I figured it out!  I ran your suggestion and didn't see any duplicates, however i noticed some `Dev_Qtr` values were displayed as asteriks because of the numeric formatting not allowing for the full length of the value.  I fixed the formatting and then the data ran!  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Glad you got it resolved, & learned something new myself as well: as it says in the [docs](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/p16njbxciji0qjn1x6y7mzktujp4.htm) for the `id` statement, "names one or more variables whose **formatted** values are used to form the names of the variables in the output data set." (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 1):

Just to summarize the comment discussion:

- For a long to wide transpose you can only have a single record for each combination of `by` and `id` variable values. This is what the error indicates.
- `id` uses *formatted* values, so while the underlying numeric values were unique their formatted ones were not (due to a format of insufficient width, probably). `PROC TRANSPOSE` tries to create the same variable within a `by` group twice and errors out. The fix was in the format.

Answer (score 0):

Hm. Maybe it's how you are reading in the data? I just gave this a try and it runs smoothly.

1. Here is how I created the data.

```
data long_data;
input Class $9. Year dev_qtr paid_loss inc_loss;
cards;
Segment_A 2004 3 1000000 1500000 
Segment_A 2004 6 950547 1425820.5
Segment_A 2004 9 971746 1457619
Segment_A 2004 15 912356 1368534
Segment_A 2004 18 26916 40374
Segment_A 2004 21 235696 353544
Segment_A 2004 27 641805 962707.5
Segment_A 2004 30 653554 980331
Segment_B 2004 3 1000000 1500000
Segment_B 2004 6 634698 952047
Segment_B 2004 9 956788 1435182
Segment_B 2004 15 18532 27798
Segment_B 2004 18 686824 1030236
Segment_B 2004 21 289675 434512.5
Segment_B 2004 27 462303 693454.5
Segment_B 2004 30 591880 887820
;
run;
```

2. Here is the **proc transpose** (unchanged).

```
proc transpose data=long_data out=Wide name=Amount;
id dev_Qtr; by class year; 
var paid_loss inc_loss;        
run;
```

The log is happy and the output data as expected.